# how to return data from mongodb query callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

when i log `points` in query callback function it returned true value  but  when i log this outside of query callback function it returned empety object {} . how to  access  `points` outside of query callback function ??

```js
crypto.find({ "date": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:") + '00' }, function (err, result ) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                result.forEach(signal => {
                    ++x
                    points[x] = {};
                    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        if (i == 1) {
                            let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                            points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                        } else if (i == 2) {
                            let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                            points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                        } else if (i == 3) {
                            let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                            points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                        }
                    }

                });

            }

         console.log(points); // loged true value
         return points;

        }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        
        console.log(points); // loged {} empety object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the console.log(points) outside the callback is probably called before the console.log(points) inside the callback. Maybe you could try something like this:

```js
async function getPoints(){
  try {
    var result = await findMongoPromise();
    console.log(result);
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log('ERROR:', error)
  }
}

function findMongoPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    crypto.find({ "date": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:") + '00' }, function (err, result ) {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        result.forEach(signal => {
            ++x
            points[x] = {};
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                    points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                    points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    let currentPrice = self.getCurrentPrice(moment(signal.date).add(i, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"));
                    points[x][i] = { currentPrice: currentPrice }
                }
            }
        });
        resolve(points);
      }
      else {
          reject('ERROR');
      }
    });
  });
}

getPoints();
```

Comment: i fixed it by async and await method ... thank for your attention @Cristian